# Undefined on localStorage.getItem in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage, undefined

I'm working on a project with multiple components that need to share data saved in local storage. I manage to save them as an object with setItem but when I'm trying to get them I get "undefined" in console.log.

Function for saving on (click):

```
  saving() {
    let dataStorage = {
      departureDate: this.departureDate,
      returnDate: this.returnDate,
      departureAirport: this.departureAirport,
      arrivalAirport: this.destinationAirport,
      passengersNumber: this.numberOfPassengers
    };
    localStorage.setItem("flightdetails", JSON.stringify(dataStorage));
    this.showStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("flightdetails"));
  }

  testLocal() {
    console.log(this.showStorage); //Here I get undefined
  }
```

All variables are declared:

```
public numberOfPassengers: number = 1;
  public departureDate: any;
  public returnDate: any;
  public departureAirport: string;
  public destinationAirport: string;
  public showStorage: any;
```

Also I'm not sure how to call local storage element in another component to display. Currently I have component called summary:

COMPONENT.TS:

```
export class SummaryComponent implements OnInit {
  public showStorage = "";
  constructor() {
    this.showStorage = localStorage.getItem("flightDetails");
  }
```

HTML for summary:

```
Departure date: {{ showStorage.departureDate}}
```

STACKBLITZ: https://stackblitz.com/edit/flight-date-pikcer

Thanks for your support in solving this!

Comment: `localStorage` isn't meant to facilitate data sharing between components. For that look into singleton services. In your case, if you call `testLocal()` function before `saving()` is complete, then the variable `showStorage` isn't assigned any value yet. And in the other component, you would do the same `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("flightDetails"))`. But it is usually good practice to check if the data obtained from local storage is `null` before trying to use it. It means the data isn't available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `showStorage` field is redeclared on each component init. So after clicking `To summary` button which redirects to another view, the `showStorage` field is destroyed as well as the whole component. After going back to the `FlightComponent`, it's initialized again and that's why the `showStorage` is `undefined`. To make it work as you expect, you can assign it a value when creating `FlightComponent`:

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.showStorage = localStorage.getItem("flightdetails") || {};
}
```

That way the variable will hold the value of your localStorage item or an empty object if the value has not been set yet.

Comment: Thanks! | Dziękuję! :) And what about the case of showing the data in Summary component? How should it be done having in mind, that I want to refer to single object elements and not to a whole element? I know how to do it in one component, but I am having a problem to do it with the getItem from localStorage.

Comment: In `localStorage`, you can store only string values. That's why you had to `JSON.stringify(dataStorage)` before saving in the `localStorage`. So to read the object from `localStorage` you need to `JSON.parse()` it: `this.showStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("flightdetails")) || {};`. Note that I use `|| {}` syntax - it's necessary for the case where the `getItem` returns `null` which would cause `JSON.parse()` to also return `null` and it could potentially result in errors later

Answer (score 1):

Well, I do get value when I try this on my console.
https://jsfiddle.net/wickedrahul/mp68hd09/2/

Chances are you might need to call `saving()` inside `testLocal()` so the value of `this.showStorage` could be assigned.

```
  function saving() {
    let dataStorage = {
      departureDate: "foo",
      returnDate: "foo",
      departureAirport: "foo",
      arrivalAirport: "foo",
      passengersNumber: "foo"
    };
    localStorage.setItem("flightdetails", JSON.stringify(dataStorage));
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("flightdetails"));
  }

  function testLocal() {
    return saving();
  }

   var a = testLocal()
   console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thank you! I added the function into test local and it helped as well. Why did you change     this.showStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("flightdetails")); into     return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("flightdetails"));?

Comment: @qshyhoo that was just to test on fiddle. In your actual code, you might like to keep `this.something` where it's present in the code.